# сайт не видит сессию

Tags: php

уважаемые знатоки!
У меня есть страница alogin.php, на которой должна происходить авторизация администратора сайта. Всё было хорошо, пока дело не дошло до сессии. На обработчик подаётся два значения методом "POST": key & pass (ключ, 12-значное число, и пароль). Идёт проверка на соответствие норме (код приложен ниже), после чего, в случае удачной авторизации запись в сессию двух параметров: "adm" = 1 и "alvl" - 0 или 1 (типа редактор или админ). Но вот проблема - сессия. Сама страница "alogin.php" её видит (var_dump показывает array(0) { }), если пытаюсь вызвать var_dump($_SESSION) на странице-обработчике - выдаёт NULL. В чём может быть проблема?

```
if(isset($_POST['alogin_form'])) {

    if(!is_numeric($_POST['key']))
        exit('Error number 1');

    if(strlen($_POST['key']) != 12)
        exit('Error number 2');

    $adminkey = $_POST['key'];

    db(); // подключение к БД

    $query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT `pass`, `lvl` FROM `admins` WHERE `adminkey` = $adminkey");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($query) == 0)
        exit('Error number 3');

    $admin = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

    if(password_verify($_POST['pass'], $admin['pass']) == FALSE)
        exit('Error number 4');

    if($_SESSION) {
        $_SESSION['adm'] = 1;
        $_SESSION['alvl'] = $admin['lvl'];
        exit('Вы успешно авторизованы');
    } else
        exit('Error number 5'); // Мне всё время как раз Error 5 выдаёт

}
```

PS: Всех с наступающим/наступившим! Удачи в 2020!

Answer (score 4):

Для работы сессий в начале скрипта укажите

```
session_start();
```